# How to bind same action for 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic code like this (that duplicates several times):

```
<h3 class="header">The header</h3>
<div class="content"> The content 
    <div class="showUp">hidden text</div>
</div>
<h3 class="header">The header2</h3>
<div class="content"> The content 2
    <div class="showUp">hidden text 2</div>
</div>
```

I want to create a roll over event that if I hover on the `h3` **or** the `div.content` the `.showup` class will be shown. I only managed to create a rule for if I roll over the `div.content` class:

```
$('.content').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".showUp").animate({left: 0},300)
})
.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".showUp").animate({
        left: -200
    }, 500);
});
```

I know I can create an event for the header like this:

```
$('h3').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this)**.next()**.find(".showUp")...
});
```

but how do I bind these to elements to do the same thing using the the word **"this"** to one function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$('.content, h3')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find('+ .content > .showUp').add($(this).find('> .showUp')).stop().animate({left: 0},300)});
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('+ .content > .showUp').add($(this).find('> .showUp')).stop().animate({left: -200},500)});
    });
```

We attach an event listener to **both** the `.content` and the `h3`. Then in the event listener we search for an immediate sibling if it exists (`+ .content > .showUp`) or an immediate child (`> .showUp`) if it exists.

So, **in any case** we'll get the `.showUp` div to animate.

I've also added the `.stop()` method to stop the animation before animating it (so it won't have some quirk behavior if you hover the `h3` and then the `.content`.

I've made here a [basic fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xF58J/), so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

make a function such "allMouseEnter" and call it from both `$('.content').mouseenter` and `$(h3).ouseenter` function. Maybe it helps you, But I am not sure. Only you can try with this.

Answer (score 0):

this example somehow didn't work (perhaps I did something wrong) but I found out that **instead of writing this:**

```
.add($(this).find('+ content > .showUp'))
```

**I wrote this and it workded for me:**

```
.add($(this).next().find('.showUp')
```